# Set state using API not working; state is an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the React component in question.

```
import React from 'react';

class JSONTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            lang: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "/jinra/api/public/test",
            success: (data) => {
                this.setState({
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description,
                    lang: data.lang
                });
            }
        })
    }


    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Title: {this.state.title}</h1>
                <p>Description: {this.state.description}</p>
                <p>Language(s): {this.state.lang}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

module.exports = JSONTest;
```

However, when I go into React Developer Tools and see what the state of the component is, it says it is an empty object, even though I clearly set the state in the constructor to have empty strings. I've tested my API call, which works fine. Here's the JSON output when I visit my API:

```
{"title":"Title","description":"This is a description.","lang":"Python"}
```

What am I doing wrong? I assumed this.setState() re-renders the view, but this is apparently not the case.

Comment: i think you need to tell `$.ajax` about the json or `JSON.parse()` the response, otherwise, `data.anything` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Adding dataType: "json" fixed the problem.